# Read a large text file and quick sort alphabetically in C program

Tags: c

I can successfully show the text's words.
But I can't alphabetically sort.

How to text's words inset to character *myArray = (char*)malloc (size);

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int compare (const void * a, const void * b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int size = 0;

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("\nFile unable to open ");
    else 
        printf("\nFile opened ");
    fseek(fp, 0, 2);    /* file pointer at the end of file */
    size = ftell(fp);   /* take a position of file pointer un size variable */
    //char *myArray =  (char*)malloc(size * sizeof *myArray);
    char *myArray = (char*)malloc(size);


    static const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if ( file != NULL ){
        int ch, word = 0, index= 0,index2 = 0;
        while ( (ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF ){
            if ( isspace(ch) || ispunct(ch) ){
                if ( word ){
                    word = 0;
                    myArray[index++] = '\n';
                   //putchar('\n');
                }
            }else{
                word = 1;
                //putchar(ch);
                myArray[index++] = ch;
                index2++;
            }
        }
        printf("%s", myArray);
        fclose(file);
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i < sizeof(myArray);i++){
            putchar(myArray[i]);
        }

        //qsort (array, 2, sizeof (const char *), compare);
        //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //    printf ("%d: %s.\n", i, array[i]);
        //}
    }
}

static int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `sizeof` operator to determine the number of elements in the array allocated via `malloc()`. By the way, why is the second argument of `qsort()` in the comment 2? Because it is `sizeof(myArray)` in some 16-bit enviromnent?

Comment: Because before l put two words into a char array,so hardcode 2.
Actually, I don't know how to fill the data clearly to the char array and how to get the size.

Comment: What happens if you try to run your code? Does it give a compilation error, a runtime error or wrong results? If the latter, please specify the expected output and actual output.

Comment: i want to read a large text file like article.but now i don't know how to fill the   text file data to the char array and how to get the size.my expect output is per word per line alphabetically.

Comment: if the text file have 200000 words, how to fill to array then sort. i use the example [link](http://www.lemoda.net/c/array-sort/). @anatolyg

Answer (score 0):

The qsort() call wants an array of pointers to character strings. So you would need to organize your words that way. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char myArray[] = "This\nis\na\nsample\ntext\nstring\nas\nthough\nfrom\nyour\nfile";
char **myWords;

//
// Compare two strings case insensitive
//
static int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    char *aStr, *bStr;
    int i, retVal;

    if ( !( aStr = strdup( *(const char **) a ) ) )
       return 1;

    if ( !( bStr = strdup( *(const char **) b ) ) ) {
       free( aStr );
       return -1;
    }

    for ( i=0; i<strlen( aStr ); i++ ) 
       aStr[i] = (char)tolower( (int)aStr[i] );

    for ( i=0; i<strlen( bStr ); i++ ) 
       bStr[i] = (char)tolower( (int)bStr[i] );

    retVal = strcmp( aStr, bStr );

    free( aStr );
    free( bStr );

    return retVal;
}

int main ()
{
    char *curWord, *nextWord;
    long wordCount;
    int i;

    //
    // myArray contains an array of newline delimited words as
    // you have in your code after reading from the file
    //
    for ( i=0; i<strlen(myArray); i++ ) 
       putchar( myArray[i] );

    //
    // If myArray is empty then no need to sort
    //
    if ( strlen( myArray ) == 0 ) {
       printf( "Nothing to sort\n" );
       return 0;
    }

    //
    // Count how many newlines are in myArray - assume at least one
    //
    for ( wordCount=1, nextWord=myArray;
          ( nextWord = strchr( nextWord, (int)'\n' ) );
          wordCount++, nextWord++ );

    //
    // If only one word then no need to sort
    //
    if ( wordCount == 1 ) {
        printf ("\n0: %s.\n", myArray );
        return 0;
    }

    // 
    // Allocate enough space to hold a new copy of each word 
    // 
    if ( !( myWords = calloc( wordCount, sizeof(char *) ) ) ) 
       return 1; 

    //
    // Load words from myArray into myWords 
    //
    curWord = nextWord = myArray; 
    i = 0;
    while ( ( nextWord = strchr( nextWord, (int)'\n' ) ) ) {
        *nextWord++ = '\0';
        myWords[i] = strdup( curWord );
        if ( !myWords[i] ) {
           printf( "\nFile too big for memory\n" );
           return 1;
        }
        i++;
        curWord = nextWord;
    }
    myWords[i] = curWord;

    //
    // Sort the array of words in myWords
    //
    qsort( myWords, wordCount, sizeof(char *), compare );

    //
    // Dump out sorted array
    //
    printf( "\n" );
    for( i = 0; i < wordCount; i++ ) 
        printf( "%d: %s.\n", i, myWords[i] );

    //
    // Free your memory here - but since exiting main() and 
    // program is ending no need to worry about it.
    //

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @T Johnson But i want to get words from the large text file into char myArray.

Comment: You state in your question that you can successfully show the words but not sort. So you have the words already in a char array as newline delimited. So my answer starts from that point.

Comment: You could let the operating system sort the file for you first, e.g., on Linux you would use 'tr -s [:space:][:punct:] \\n < data.txt | sort -u > data.out' and then you only need to read from data.out and dump to the console as qsort() is no longer needed since the data.out file is sorted. Otherwise you need to keep a structure that allows you to recognize that a word is already in your collection of words, and if it is then don't add it again to the collection.

Comment: @T Johnson If i use c program,how to do it

Comment: Removing duplicates can run very slowly if the data structure is not well designed. Worst case you end up searching n squared times where n is the number of words in your file. Search for BST on the web and you will find examples that run faster.

Comment: In stdlib.h there is a function named bsearch(). Search for examples on the internet using bsearch().